# using bash or variables within Chef Inspec

Tags: linux, chef-infra, inspec

Im new to Chef /Inspec test writing.
What Im trying to do is validate a host name/IP address within a file and match it to what is in DNS.  If the IP address in file doesnt match what is in DNS, the test should fail.

example

```
describe host('example.com') do
  it { should be_resolvable }
  its('ipaddress') { should include '12.34.56.78' }
  its('stdout') { should match 'ipaddress' }
end
```

the *'example.com'* would be a $variable that comes from within a file

the *''12.34.56.78'* would also be a $variable that comes from within a file however should match what is in DNS

Is this even possible to do?  do I need to or can I use a bash script within the inspec file that has some awk commands?

```
describe bash('filename.sh') do
  it { should be_resolvable }
  its('stdout') { should match 'ipaddress' }
  its('stderr') { should eq '' }
  its('ipaddress') { should include '12.34.56.78' }
end
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.  Thank you!!

Comment: Actually what I think Im looking for is to create some ruby code that I can use in conjunction with inspec tests since the inspec will be a ruby file.

Comment: Since you want to mix and match contents of a file with the DNS configuration, having a shell script do all the checks and returning appropriate `stdout`/`stderr` is a good option.